# Why does the column transformer give a compressed sparse row format?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

When I use OneHotEncoder using column transformer on this dataset, it results in a compressed sparse row format. After encoding, I wanted to split the data using train_test_split but that showed this error:

```
Singleton array array(<32561x105 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 394963 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
      dtype=object) cannot be considered a valid collection.
```

First I deal with missing values like this

```
    from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
    imputer_nominal = SimpleImputer(missing_values = np.nan, strategy = 'most_frequent')
    imputer_numerical = SimpleImputer(missing_values = np.nan, strategy = 'mean')
    imputer_nominal.fit(x[:,[1,3,5,6,7,8,9,13]])
    x[:,[1,3,5,6,7,8,9,13]] = imputer_nominal.transform(x[:,[1,3,5,6,7,8,9,13]])
    imputer_numerical.fit(x[:,[0,2,4,10,11,12]])
    x[:,[0,2,4,10,11,12]] = imputer_numerical.transform(x[:,[0,2,4,10,11,12]])
```

Then I encode the data:

```
    from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
    from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
    ct = ColumnTransformer(transformers = [('encoder', OneHotEncoder(), [1,3,5,6,7,8,9,13])], remainder = 'passthrough')
    x = np.array(ct.fit_transform(x))
```

When I output the numpy array 'x' it looks like this which is a compressed sparse row format

```
    (0, 6)  1.0
      (0, 17)   1.0
      (0, 28)   1.0
      (0, 31)   1.0
      (0, 46)   1.0
      (0, 55)   1.0
      (0, 57)   1.0
      (0, 96)   1.0
      (0, 99)   39.0
```

After this I try to split the data and it shows the error above. I have uesd column transformer and OneHotEncoder before but I don't know what went wrong with this one. Also, I don't use scipy library anywhere in this code.

Comment: Tell us about `ct.fit_transform(x)`.Also read the docs of `ColumnTransformer`.  `scikit-learn` uses the scipy sparse fornat for some inputs and results.

Comment: You may convert a csr matrix to `ndarray` with the `toarray` method. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.toarray.html

Comment: Yes the column transformer converts it to a sparse matrix, that is why I convert it to a numpy array first. When I print the type of 'x' it does show ndarray but generates error at splitting stage saying it is stored in CSR format.

Comment: You can't convert it with `np.array(...)`

Comment: I used toarray() like you said and it worked. But I have used np.array() before and it uesd to work fine. If I'm not bothering you, can you tell me why didn't it work with np.array() ?

Comment: `np.array` does not "know" anything about `scipy.sparse` objects, so it just naively wraps it in an object dtype array.  It does not convert it in any way.  `sparse` is not a subclass of `ndarray`.

Comment: Okay, Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

My ColumnTransformer created compressed sparse data as well. I made sparse_threshold=0 in the function. Its default value is 0.3. This seems to be a new attribute/value since I've seen videos of ColumnTransformer not need it and create the same results. Here's my code if it'll help.

Original Code:

```
#This data is for a car sales CSV
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
categorical_features = ["Make", "Colour", "Doors"]
one_hot = OneHotEncoder()
transformer = ColumnTransformer([('one_hot',
                             one_hot,
                             categorical_features)],
                             remainder ='passthrough',
                           sparse_threshold=0)
transformed_X = transformer.fit_transform(X)
transformed_X[:1], pd.DataFrame(transformed_X).head()
```

Original Output:

```
(<1x16 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 4 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
                                                    0
 0    (0, 1)\t1.0\n  (0, 9)\t1.0\n  (0, 12)\t1.0\n...
 1    (0, 0)\t1.0\n  (0, 6)\t1.0\n  (0, 13)\t1.0\n...
 2    (0, 1)\t1.0\n  (0, 9)\t1.0\n  (0, 12)\t1.0\n...
 3    (0, 3)\t1.0\n  (0, 9)\t1.0\n  (0, 12)\t1.0\n...
 4    (0, 2)\t1.0\n  (0, 6)\t1.0\n  (0, 11)\t1.0\n...)
```

Code with Sparse_thresh:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
categorical_features = ["Make", "Colour", "Doors"]
one_hot = OneHotEncoder()
transformer = ColumnTransformer([('one_hot',
                                 one_hot,
                                 categorical_features)],
                                 remainder ='passthrough',
                               sparse_threshold=0)
transformed_X = transformer.fit_transform(X)
#put in data frame for viewing
transformed_X[:1], pd.DataFrame(transformed_X).head()
```

Output Code with sparse_threshold=0 (Column 15 is Odometer Values):

```
(array([[0.0000e+00, 1.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00,
         0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00, 1.0000e+00,
         0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00, 1.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00,
         3.5431e+04]]),
     0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10   11   12   13   14  \
 0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0   
 1  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0   
 2  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0   
 3  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0   
 4  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   
 
          15  
 0   35431.0  
 1  192714.0  
 2   84714.0  
 3  154365.0  
 4  181577.0  )
```